# Asp .Net Core MVC return cached data requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a login page where client inserts his id number and an ajax request is done to a controller to fetch data based on that parameter.

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 5, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
public IActionResult GetAll(id)
{
    var client = _context.Clients.Find(id);

    var references = _context.References.Where(r => r.ClientId == clientId).ToList();

    if(references == null)
    {
        return new JsonResult("No references found.");
    }

    return new JsonResult(references);
}
```

I was wondering when trying to use responsecache, if another client is trying to log in as well, will he get the cached data for the current client?

Answer (score 0):

> if another client is trying to log in as well, will he get the cached data for the current client?

No , `Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client` makes the "private" value for Cache-Control header indicates that the value for the response message is intended for single user. It is not stored in shared cache.